# Using VueUse composables with the component options api

Tags: vue.js, vueuse

Is possible to use VueUse with the Options API style? All examples are using Composition one.

I try to use `computedAsync`. The `stock` function returns a `Promise<VendorItem[]>`.

Using Composition API as the example works fine :

```js
const vendors = computedAsync(
    async () => {
        return await stock(db);
    },
    [],
);
```

But this does not work when I try to use it using the Options API style:

```js
export default defineComponent({
    name: "VendorsList",
    computed: {
        vendors() {
            return computedAsync(
                async () => {
                    return await stock(db);
                },
                [],
            )
        }
    }
})
```

In the last case, `vendors` does not contain the array.
I try to debug it adding:

```html
    <div v-for="vendor in vendors" class="">
        <pre>{{ JSON.stringify(vendor, null, 4)}}</pre>
        ---------------
    </div>
```

and the output is something like this

```
false
---------------
---------------
true
---------------
[
    {
        "id": "00PIL9ljDrgRZrP8MOkl",
        "language": "en"
    },
    {
        "id": "00ZnoY0NXb1ZjQMFQJCC",
        "language": "en"
    },
    {
        "id": "01hO4DKjAprwP8zwUpZU",
        "language": "en"
    }
]
---------------
[
    {
        "id": "00PIL9ljDrgRZrP8MOkl",
        "language": "en"
    },
    {
        "id": "00ZnoY0NXb1ZjQMFQJCC",
        "language": "en"
    },
    {
        "id": "01hO4DKjAprwP8zwUpZU",
        "language": "en"
    }
]
---------------
```

Comment: No, you can't use VueUse composables in the option api except for the `setup` function. The `computedAsync` composable already creates a computed, so here you are trying to create a computed of a computed. Just move it in the `setup` function and it will work.

Comment: Thank @Kapcash Now, I get how it is working.  To me, this looks like a response. If you write it as an Answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple anwser is **no, you can't use vue composables (including VueUse ones) in the option api except for the setup function**. Source in the [vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#using-composables-in-options-api).

The `computedAsync` composable already creates a computed, so here you are trying to create a computed of a computed. Just move it in the setup function and it will work.

```js
export default defineComponent({
  name: "VendorsList",
  setup() {
    const vendors = computedAsync(async () => await stock(db), [])
    return { vendors }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can** incorporate VueUse in your options API.

This is a small example I have.

```
{
  data: function () {
    return {
      // Reactive data properties here
      selectedProgramme: VueUse.useSessionStorage('P3Selections.PG', ''),
      selectedProject: VueUse.useSessionStorage('P3Selections.PJ', ''),
      filterOptions: VueUse.useSessionStorage('ChgReg.PrepNSubmit.FilterOpts',
        {
          showDraft: true,
          showSumitted: true,
          showApproved: true,
          showRejected: true,
          showClosed: false
        }),
        /// More stuff here
      }
    }
}
```

In this case my entire Vue App is built using old fashioned  tags and CDN version of Vue and VueUse (don't ask, sometimes you just got to do what you have to do with what you got!)

I have only used a handful of the many fetaures of VueUse, you may have to use some of them in a **mounted** hook where the require a specific element to bind to.

Example :-

```
{
  data() {
    return {
      scrollStuff: null
    }
  },
  // hooks
  mounted() {
    this.scrollStuff = VueUse.useScroll(this.$refs.myPanel)
  },
  template: `
  <div ref="myPanel"  style="width:6rem;height:6rem;overflow:scroll">
    <p>stuff here<br>Lines follow:-</p>
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>five</li>
      <li>6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  `}
}
```

See a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/darren_h_gill/ynvuo4dj/)
and since VueUse is an open source project you can use some of their code as a template to see how to make your own!